# How do I fix python?

Tags: command-line, python

I mistakenly thought that Ubuntu only came pre-loaded with Python 2.x, so I ran the command

```
sudo apt-get remove python-minimal
```

so I could install python3 as default.  I soon learned this was unnecessary, and I could have ran the `python3` terminal by typing `python3` instead of `python`, but I realized that by removing `python-minimal` I deleted other applications, including the original Ubuntu default terminal (I am now forced to use XTerm or UXTerm) and the Ubuntu Software Center.

How do I fix this?  Even installing and reinstalling python-minimal doesn't seem to do anything for the missing applications.

Answer (score 4):

Do an `apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`. This will reinstall all the packages part of the default setup.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that running `sudo apt-get remove python-minimal` removed all packages that depend on it. You could not use them anyway and you said you know what you are doing (by typing `sudo`), so Ubuntu just saves disk space.

All programs that came pre-installed in Ubuntu can be reinstalled running `sudo apt-get install ubuntu-desktop`.

It fixed when I deleted `python` altogether and GUI didn't load at all ^^.